# Cannot focus text instantly contenteditable when set attribute false to true reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

First, I have a state is `showSpan`, this state manipulate the show/hidden of a `span`.
Inside component:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false);

return <>
<div onMouseDown={()=>{setShowSpan(true)}}>
{state ? (
          <span
            contentEditable={`true`}
            onFocus={() => {
              console.log("focus");
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
              setState(false);
            }}
          >
            Text can focus first time
            <br />
            <i>Text cannot focus first time</i>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <>
            Text can focus first time
            <br />
            <i>Text cannot focus first time</i>
          </>
        )}
</div>
</>
```

The main course is when I trigger mouse down event, state changes then component mutates and finally `span` is shown, I want when I trigger event mouse down on `div`, it also trigger focus on text at the cursor position instantly. I have tried clicking on text, it worked but if the text is insided a tag ( in this case is `i` ), it didn't work.And the required is the `span` is shown only when focus, How can I fix this problem?

Sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-black-48ru59?file=/src/App.js:413-1150

Answer (score 1):

With your conditional rendering, React will mount an other child when the state is mounted. Thus, I thing the event propagation will not occur correctly.

The solution to this is to keep your `span` mounted and to pass the `contentEditable` props from the state.

```
<div onMouseDown={() => setState(true)}>
  <span
    contentEditable={state}
    onBlur={() => {
      setState(false);
    }}
  >
    Text can focus first time
    <br />
    Text can focus first time
    <br />
    Text can focus first time
    <br />
    <i>Text can focus first time</i>
  </span>
  <br />
</div>
```

Codesandox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-banzai-mj03dl

Comment: thanks @maxencedhx for replying, but the required is `span` only shown when it focus :<. Is there any ways ?

Comment: @pcldev can you explain more why you absolutely need the `span` ? There are some other solutions we can do but without context it's hard to decide which's the best for your need

Comment: thanks for your helpful @maxencedhx. First, I have ```<h3>
<i>One icon</i>
 <span contenteditable="true">Some text...</span>
</h3>```,
I have a required that the `span` need to be removed and the component still can be edited, it will be like ```<h3><i>One icon</i>Some text...</h3>```, the main course is return only text without `span`,  I have an idea is only when focus or some other event will show span like the INITIAL COMPONENT, and finally after edited by blur event, the `span` must be removed by required.